# Tensorflow Dataset API: input pipeline with parquet files

Tags: tensorflow, pipeline, parquet

I am trying to design an input pipeline with Dataset API. I am working with parquet files. What is a good way to add them to my pipeline?

Answer (score 7):

We have released [Petastorm](https://github.com/uber/petastorm), an open source library that allows you to use Apache Parquet files directly via Tensorflow Dataset API.

Here is a small [example](https://github.com/uber/petastorm/blob/master/examples/hello_world/tensorflow_hello_world.py):

```
   with Reader('hdfs://.../some/hdfs/path') as reader:
        dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(reader)
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        tensor = iterator.get_next()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sample = sess.run(tensor)
            print(sample.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but looks like this is available directly within Tensorflow now.

https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/IODataset#from_parquet

[image]