# Python: Reading Parquet files stored on s3 using petastorm generates connection warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, urllib3, petastorm

I have a Tensorflow model that I would like to feed with parquet files stored on s3. I'm using `petastorm` to query these files from s3 and the result of the query is stored as a Tensorflow dataset thanks to `petastorm.tf_utils.make_petastorm_dataset`.

Here's the code I used (mainly inspired from this thread [Tensorflow Dataset API: input pipeline with parquet files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732446/tensorflow-dataset-api-input-pipeline-with-parquet-files)):

```py
import s3fs
from pyarrow.filesystem import S3FSWrapper
from petastorm.reader import Reader
from petastorm.tf_utils import make_petastorm_dataset

dataset_url = "analytics.xxx.xxx" #s3 bucket name

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
wrapped_fs = S3FSWrapper(fs)

with Reader(pyarrow_filesystem=wrapped_fs, dataset_path=dataset_url) as reader:
    dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(reader)
```

This works pretty well, except that it generates 20+ lines of connection warnings:

```
W0514 18:56:42.779965 140231344908032 connectionpool.py:274] Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
W0514 18:56:42.782773 140231311337216 connectionpool.py:274] Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
W0514 18:56:42.854569 140232468973312 connectionpool.py:274] Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
W0514 18:56:42.868761 140231328122624 connectionpool.py:274] Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
W0514 18:56:42.885518 140230816429824 connectionpool.py:274] Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
...
```

According to this thread [urllib3 connectionpool - Connection pool is full, discarding connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765366/urllib3-connectionpool-connection-pool-is-full-discarding-connection), it's certainly related to `urllib3`, but I can't figure a way to get rid of these warnings.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer on Github: https://github.com/uber/petastorm/issues/376.
Use the connection pool setting for `boto3` and increase the `max_pool_connections`:

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(config_kwargs = {'max_pool_connections': 50})
```